# Get closest date compared to current date ACF

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a huge question. I am printing out my events in Wordpress (WP) as custom post + acf. Everything works fine but I need to sort my events to show the closest events at the top. Is there any easy way to do this?

My Code looks like this currently:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Program Template
*/
$today = date('Ymd');
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'program',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
get_header(); ?>
<div id="particle-canvas">
    <h1 class="page-title">Program</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid program">
    <div class="row">
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6 program__program-content">
                <div class="overlay-box">
                    <span><?php $date_value = get_field('date', $post_id);
                        echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date_value)); ?></span>
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(array(645, 246)); ?>" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <div class="button">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                <p>More</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably try asking for help for that in [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok I found Out myself what I can do ;) this can be closed !

Comment: I guess you can flag your own question if you want, or maybe you have a delete option. Not sure tough. Just add an answer with your solution, it's better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Please add 'meta_key' in your query, just like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'program',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'date',
    'meta_type'   => 'DATE',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
));
```

Change the 'order' => 'ASC/DESC' according to your requirement.

Hope, this may help you.